# Monnify Transaction Verification Issue,

Tags: php, laravel

I ma currently integrating the Monnify payment system but I'm getting errors.

Here is my code;

```
public function validatePayment(Request $request){
        //dd($request->input());
        $url = ENV('MONNIFY_BASE_URL').'/api/v2/transactions/'.urlencode($request->transactionReference);
        //dd($url);
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer ".base64_encode(ENV('MONNIFY_API_KEY').":".ENV("MONNIFY_SECRET_KEY")),            
            
            );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        //for debug only!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $resp = json_decode($resp, true);
        dd($resp);

        

    }
```

When i die dump respose, this is what I get

```
^ array:2 [▼
  "error" => "invalid_token"
  "error_description" => "Cannot convert access token to JSON"
]
```

Here is a link to the documentation

https://teamapt.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/MON/pages/213909851/Get+Transaction+Status

What could be problem?

For any one who wants to try this, here are the test keys

```
MONNIFY_API_KEY=MK_TEST_FWD6HTML35
MONNIFY_SECRET_KEY=5Y8ZBQMSEUXMTQMHFAV3U3A34NNYH1X5
MONNIFY_BASE_URL=https://sandbox.monnify.com
```

Also here the test transaction reference that I want to verify

```
MNFY|05|20220703011128|000322
```

Comment: Pretty sure you just gave away your Monify account

Comment: @RiggsFolly those are test keys and can be regenerated

Comment: isn't you are supposed to get `access token` using both `api key` and `secret key` first before sending request to transaction endpoint? like in [the docs](https://teamapt.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/MON/pages/212008633/Authorization).

Comment: @BagusTesa thank you for this , you saved my life. Wow! I need to pay more attention next time

Answer (score -1):

To Integrate the Monnify Payment into your php app, follow the following steps:

Assumptions:

- API Key: MK_TEST_ABCDEFGHIJ
- Contract Code: 1234567890
- Secret Key: ABCDEFGHIJ1234567890ABCDEF12345

Visit your [Monnify Dashboard](https://app.monnify.com/dashboard) to get your actual keys.

In your front end, initiate the request by placing the following script right above the closing body tag `</body>`:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sdk.monnify.com/plugin/monnify.js"></script>
    <script>
        function pay(id) {
            MonnifySDK.initialize({
                amount: id,
                currency: "NGN",
                reference: new String((new Date()).getTime()),
                customerFullName: "Customer Name",
                customerEmail: "customer@email.com",
                apiKey: "MK_TEST_ABCDEFGHIJ",
                contractCode: "1234567890",
                paymentDescription: "Monnify Payment",
                metadata: {
                    "name": "Engr. Ukairo",
                    "age": 450,
                },
                onLoadStart: () => {
                    console.log("loading has started");
                },
                onLoadComplete: () => {
                    console.log("SDK is UP");
                },
                onComplete: function(response) {
                    //Implement what happens when the transaction is completed.
                    window.location.href = home+"paymentverify.php?ref="+response.transactionReference;
                    console.log(response);
                },
                onClose: function(data) {
                    //Implement what should happen when the modal is closed here
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Make sure the `home` in the onComplete function is defined. In the paymentverify.php file, you first need to generate an access token, then use the access token and other details to query the result of the payment. Put the following code inside your paymentverify.php file:

```html
<?php
function index($ref)
{
    $ref = urlencode($ref);
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandbox.monnify.com/api/v2/transactions/' . $ref . '', 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', 
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0, 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, 
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => 
    CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1, 
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET'));
    curl_setopt(
        $curl,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Authorization: Bearer $accessToken")
    );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $res = json_decode($response, true);
    $responseBody = $res['responseBody'];
    if ($responseBody["paymentStatus"] == "PAID") {
        //payment was successful
        //credit user
        //amount paid = $responseBody["amountPaid"];
        //paid on = $responseBody["paidOn"];
        //or substr($responseBody["paidOn"], 0, 16);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
        //payment not verified
    }
}

function getAccessToken()
{
    $auth = base64_encode("MK_TEST_ABCDEFGHIJ:ABCDEFGHIJ1234567890ABCDEF12345");
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://sandbox.monnify.com/api/v1/auth/login/',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Basic $auth"));
    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
    curl_close($curl);
    //Assign accessToken to var
    $access_token = $response['responseBody']['accessToken'];
    return $access_token;
}
```

Remember to use your actual keys and contract codes. Visit your [Monnify Dashboard](https://app.monnify.com/dashboard) to get your keys. [This github repository](https://github.com/jimiejosh/monnify-php-sample-codes/) contains some codes too. Happy coding!